Is there a function in REDCap
I am conducting a survey on REDCap that is anonymous. We want to make a "giftcard draw" for those who have answered the survey. However, in order to be in the drawing, they have to enter their email address. This means, that the survey would not be anonymous anymore. We could also make a second survey, which the participants would be redirected to from the main survey, where the email information could be collected. However, Redcap uses timestamps, which in theory means, that the survey isn't entirely anonymous, as the timestamps could be crosschecked.
My question is. Is there any way emails can be collected in REDCap, without compromising anonymity?

The model you suggest of using the public survey URL of a second REDCap project as the redirect URL in the survey termination section of the first survey's survey settings is the usual way to accomplish the effective separation of the identifying data from the survey responses.
If you're worried about someone breaking anonymity by cross-checking timestamps then enforce a restriction that no user has access to both the main survey project and the email address capture project.
